# How to get post id when we share our content using share dialog?

Tags: angularjs, cordova, facebook-graph-api

I am phone-gap developer. I make a application for getting like and comment via post image caption on Facebook. So we are using a plugin of iOS and android for the same but i am not getting any post-id in return after sharing the image through default share dialog in both.

Plugin Link : https://github.com/jeduan/cordova-plugin-facebook4

Use Case in android :-

1- We are getting post-id when Facebook application is not installed in device.
2- But we are unable to get the post-id when Facebook application is installed in the device.

Use Case in iPhone :-

1- We don't get any response after sharing  images in iPhone device.
2- But getting response (post-id) when share through simulator.

Please help me with proper solution. It would be great if you join us in team-viewer to solve our problem.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: why do you need the post id?

Comment: I need post id because we need to get number of likes and comments on shared post by the user. Thanks in advanced.

Comment: ok, and what for do you need those exactly? that is a very important question, i am sorry.

Comment: When we received post id after the share then we user graph api and get how many Facebook users likes and comments on shared post

Comment: we know that already, but WHAT FOR do you need to know those numbers exactly?

Comment: I can't understand what information you want for me all the use cases i mentioned above. Thanks for your patience.

Comment: the question is what you want to do with the numbers. i assume you dont just want to get the numbers to store them in a database ;)

Comment: We paid user on basis of number of likes and comments get by user on shared post

Answer (score 0):

The only way to get the post id is to authorize users with the `publish_actions` permission - you would also need the `user_posts` permission to get access to the new post in order to get the likes/comments. According to your comments, you want to pay users for those - which is not allowed and Facebook will never approve the required permission in the neccessary login review process.

In other words: It is not allowed and not possible.

Comment: can you explain why facebook not allowed above scenario.

Comment: because user profiles are not meant to be used for commercial stuff, for example. it is called "incentivizing", which is clearly forbidden in the platform policy. please need to share stuff on their wall ONLY because they want to show it to their friends, not because they get something for it.